# .htaccess redirect single domain to https instead of all domains (aliases) redirected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have example.com and alias sub.example.com pointing to the same directory. I want all http://example.com redirect to https://example.com, but keep sub.example.com non-ssl

Here is what I try, but it is not redirecting example.com to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(http:\/\/example\.com.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` doesn't match domain name. You will need to use a `RewriteCond` for that like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```